# jQuery Mobile slide down event

Tags: jquery, mobile, slide

Looking at jQuery Mobile I can see events for SlideLeft and SlideRight.

I need a SlideDown event. The idea is in my app when you do a slide down action (swipe finger down motion) on the screen it forces a refresh of the data displayed.

Looking at the Slide event it seems to support horizontal motion, but not vertical.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean a pull to refresh feature, is not implemented by design in jQuery mobile.

You can use a specific plugin like [scrollz](https://github.com/zippy1978/jquery.scrollz).

Code:

```
        <!-- Content : data-scrollz supports 'simple' or 'pull'. Content is automatically resized to  the window height between header and footer. -->
        <div id="content" data-role="content" data-scrollz="pull">
                <!-- Scrollable content here. -->
        </div>
```

Demo: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26978903/scrollz/mobile.html